# mysql works fine after first time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a strange problem which is when I run the sql command first time it shows wrong result, but when I run the same code for second time the result is correct. 
The wrong result is:

[image: wrong result]

The expected result is:

[image: correct result]

the sql command is:

```
                SELECT srNumber, end_on, start_on, teamEntityId
                FROM (
                        SELECT srNumber, end_on, start_on, teamEntityId,
                            @lastrow := IF(@sr_Number = srNumber, @lastrow + 1,
                                            IF(@sr_Number := srNumber, 1, 0)) AS lastrow
                        FROM assign
                        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @lastrow := 0, @sr_Number = '') AS vars
                        ORDER By srNumber, assignId DESC) AS t
                WHERE t.lastrow = 1 AND t.teamEntityId = '00000168752ac161-02420aff00230001'
```

Comment: probably `@sr_Number = ''` missing colon symbol -> `@sr_Number := ''`

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, then consider replacing your current approach with an inbuilt analytic function.

Comment: `@sr_Number = ''` does not modify the variable. You need to use `:=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank **Alex** and **Salman A** who solved the problem which is:

replace the below code

```
 @sr_Number = ''
```

to

```
@sr_Number := ''
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of MySQL, you need to order the data *before* using variables.  So replace:

```
FROM assign
```

with:

```
FROM (SELECT a.* FROM assign a ORDER BY srNumber, assignId DESC) a
```